# Can I use Moondust as a splash weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, traps, improvised-weaponry

Would it be possible to carry moondust, from Sandstorm, in a flask and attempt to use it as a thrown splash weapon, forcing saves against suffocation?  If so, how terrible of an idea is this?  If building from a budget, what would a reasonable cost be?

Comment: Costing Moondust would depend on where your supplier is getting it. Does your hypothetical character have access to or know someone with access to the Elemental Plane of Earth or an actual moon?

Answer (score 8):

### The Short Answer

Yes, it's possible to carry *Sandstorm*'s moondust in a flask. Yes, it's possible to use it as a thrown splash weapon. No, it won't induce suffocation; it'll just make your enemies filthy.

### The Long Answer

*Sandstorm*'s moondust (23) is a hazard, like green slime (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 76) and anchor mists (*Dungeonscape* 140). You can no more weaponize moondust than you can other hazards. They're toys for the Dungeon Master for making the world more dangerous, and, unless character options permit, they're typically beyond the reach of players.<sup>1</sup>

Further, moondust appears to be something to suffocate in, useful when the DM wants to have nasty trap and water (or green slime or vanilla pudding or hot melted cheese) is inappropriate. The amount of moondust needed to suffocate a creature goes unmentioned, but as the later reference in *Sandstorm* indicates, "natural sinkholes filled with moondust" (32) are a thing. So while you could *bury* a foe in moondust and laugh as he died a dirty death, throwing a flask of it on a foe will just ruin his suit and tick him off.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The *Dungeon* #146 Seeds of Sehan adventure "Spawn of Sehan" presents this variant rule:

> #### Green Slime as a Weapon
>
> With a bit of ingenuity, player characters might be able to use green slime as a weapon. Assuming they make a DC 12 Dexterity check to avoid contact with it and have a suitable container with which to scoop it up, they could use it to make a splash attack similar to an attack with holy water. A hit deals 1d2 points of Constitution damage per round as it slowly consumes organic matter and grows. There is no splash damage, but in the event of a miss, creatures within 5 feet must succeed on a DC 15 Reflex save to avoid contact with it. (32)

I mean, it's *D&D 3.5*, so if you look hard enough you'll probably find an exception *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever method you use to attain this item is up to your DM, as is the result when you take the stopper of the flask/break said container.
For my game I bent the world a bit and turned the wizard Mordenkainen, from Greyhawk, into a traveling merchant aswel as a mighty wizard.

If anything I would try to treat it as a thrown item resulting in a local Sandstorm/Tornado, which can cause suffocation, slow, blindness ie. at the location it lands. You could even roll a d8 to determine the direction it travels and a d4 for it's speed.

Or if your DM is feeling generous, try attaining it as a magic item that causes a Sandstorm/Tornado under your control?